# print output in seperate lines while using sorted()

Tags: python

I have a function that prints a sorted list of students from a CSV file, but it obviously prints it as a list of tuples. Is there a way I can change the code so that every line gets printed separately? I tried adding `sep="\n"` or `"\n"` on its own and it does not work. Sorry the code is partly in polish. I tried looking it up on google, but found nothing. I also cannot use any libraries.

```
def sortowanie():

    print("Wybierz opcje sortowania listy studentów:")
    print("""
    1. Wyświetl dane o studentach posortowane po ocenach malejąco.
    2. Wyświetl studentów w porządku alfabetycznym.
    3. Wyświetl dane o studentach posortowane po numerach albumów rosnąco. 
    4. Wyświetl dane studenta z najwyższą oceną.
    5. Wyświetl studenta z najniższą oceną.
             """)

    with open('students.csv') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
        students = [(n, s, int(nu), float(g)) for (n, s, nu, g) in lines]

    for x in students:      
        try:
            y = int(input("Wybrana opcja > "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Proszę wybrać poprawny numer.")  

        if y == 1:
            print(sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[3], reverse=True))
        if y == 2:
            print(sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[1]))
        if y == 3:
            print(sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[2]))
        if y == 4:
            print(max(students, key=lambda s: s[3]))
        if y == 5:
            print(min(students, key=lambda s: s[3]))
        else:
           break
        break

 sortowanie()
```

Comment: You already have a `for x in students` loop, so `x` is the current student entry.  Just print `x`.

Comment: Well, `students` *is* a list of tuples. Why would it not be printed as a list of tuples? Anyway, you could use `'\n'.join(map(str, students))` but it might be better to rethink the entire logic/design

Comment: tried printing x and it gives me 'int' object is not subscriptable". I may have to rethink the whole structure like DeepSpace suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
def sortowanie():

    print("Wybierz opcje sortowania listy studentów:")
    print("""
    1. Wyświetl dane o studentach posortowane po ocenach malejąco.
    2. Wyświetl studentów w porządku alfabetycznym.
    3. Wyświetl dane o studentach posortowane po numerach albumów rosnąco. 
    4. Wyświetl dane studenta z najwyższą oceną.
    5. Wyświetl studenta z najniższą oceną.
             """)

    with open('students.csv') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
        students = [(n, s, int(nu), float(g)) for (n, s, nu, g) in lines]

    for x in students:      
        try:
            y = int(input("Wybrana opcja > "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Proszę wybrać poprawny numer.")  

        if y == 1:
            [print(x) for x in sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[3], reverse=True)]
        if y == 2:
            [print(x) for x in sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[1])]
        if y == 3:
            [print(x) for x in sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[2])]
        if y == 4:
            print(max(students, key=lambda s: s[3]))
        if y == 5:
            print(min(students, key=lambda s: s[3]))
        else:
           break
        break

sortowanie()
```

Instead of printing the list, you can use a comprehension to print each item in the list separately, and default behavior of `print` is to end with a newline.

Comment: Oh my god! Why did I not think of that? It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Pass the list (or tuple) items to the `print` function as `*args` and a parameter that separates each item which is `\n` in our case

```
print(*sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[3], reverse=True), sep='\n')
```

### Method 2

Iterate through all the items and print them in a new line

```
for item in sorted(students, key=lambda s: s[3], reverse=True):
    print(item)
```